# Is there a testing framework that works with threads in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, integration-testing

I understand this question might get closed, downvoted etc. Nonetheless there's no better forum than SO to ask so here goes.

I have a publisher in python in thread 1 and subscriber in thread 2. I am trying to code up integration tests where my publisher thread sends data to an enterprise bus and after delta time the subscriber callback happens in thread 2. That's the general pattern, and until the first test completes I don't move to test 2.

I have been investigating frameworks for this but nothing seems to have exactly what I need. The closest that something came was tornado's asynctest http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/testing.html but then that's all event driven and I am looking for something similar but for threads.

I am sure this problem has been solved elegantly somewhere. If it helps I am on Python 2.7.

Comment: more than you think.

Comment: Any testing framework will allow you to test threaded code *with care*. I'd personally give [pytest](http://pytest.org) a go.

Comment: Having *carefully* read your requirements as you described them; I think you'l have to come up with a pseudo framework yourself say using [pytest](http://pytest.org) and maybe a library to help/assist in coordinating the integration/testing. I think the "threading" side of things is irrelevant IHMO.